# Change text with an image in a code

Tags: image, icons, loading

Can somebody help me please, I have this code :

```
$('childcat').setHTML('Loading...');
```

I would like to put a image/icon instead of just "Loading..." text...

Can somebody please help ?

Thank you
Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a snippet of HTML there (it's `set*HTML*` after all):

```
$('childcat').setHTML('<img src="/images/loading.png" alt="Loading..."/>');
```